# how to start a customview animation in appdelegate launch function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartzcode

I had generated an animation code with QuartzCode App.
I got 4 files:

- CustomView.h
- CustomView.m
- QCMethod.h
- QCMethod.m

How to add this animation in AppDelegate.m in order to generate a tricky splash screen animation just after the launch screen defined?

**CustomView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CustomView : UIView

- (void)addJumpAnimation;
- (void)addJumpAnimationCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock;
- (void)addJumpHighAnimation;
- (void)addJumpHighAnimationCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock;
- (void)removeAnimationsForAnimationId:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)removeAllAnimations;

@end
```

**CustomView.m**

```
#import "CustomView.h"
#import "QCMethod.h"

@interface CustomView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * layers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMapTable * completionBlocks;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL  updateLayerValueForCompletedAnimation;


@end

@implementation CustomView

#pragma mark - Life Cycle

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setupProperties];
        [self setupLayers];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupProperties];
        [self setupLayers];
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)setupProperties{
    self.completionBlocks = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory valueOptions:NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory];;
    self.layers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

}

- (void)setupLayers{
    CALayer * ggk = [CALayer layer];
    ggk.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [self.layer addSublayer:ggk];
    self.layers[@"ggk"] = ggk;

    [self resetLayerPropertiesForLayerIdentifiers:nil];
}

- (void)resetLayerPropertiesForLayerIdentifiers:(NSArray *)layerIds{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

    if(!layerIds || [layerIds containsObject:@"ggk"]){
        CALayer * ggk = self.layers[@"ggk"];
        ggk.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"ggk"].CGImage;
    }

    [CATransaction commit];
}

#pragma mark - Animation Setup

- (void)addJumpAnimation{
    [self addJumpAnimationCompletionBlock:nil];
}

- (void)addJumpAnimationCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock{
    if (completionBlock){
        CABasicAnimation * completionAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"completionAnim"];;
        completionAnim.duration = 2.5;
        completionAnim.delegate = self;
        [completionAnim setValue:@"Jump" forKey:@"animId"];
        [completionAnim setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"needEndAnim"];
        [self.layer addAnimation:completionAnim forKey:@"Jump"];
        [self.completionBlocks setObject:completionBlock forKey:[self.layer animationForKey:@"Jump"]];
    }

    NSString * fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    ////ggk animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation * ggkOpacityAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    ggkOpacityAnim.values    = @[@1, @0];
    ggkOpacityAnim.keyTimes  = @[@0, @1];
    ggkOpacityAnim.duration  = 0.5;
    ggkOpacityAnim.beginTime = 2;

    CAKeyframeAnimation * ggkPositionAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    ggkPositionAnim.values   = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 0)]];
    ggkPositionAnim.keyTimes = @[@0, @0.1, @0.2, @0.3, @0.4, @0.5, @0.6, @0.7, @0.8, @1];
    ggkPositionAnim.duration = 2.5;

    CAAnimationGroup * ggkJumpAnim = [QCMethod groupAnimations:@[ggkOpacityAnim, ggkPositionAnim] fillMode:fillMode];
    [self.layers[@"ggk"] addAnimation:ggkJumpAnim forKey:@"ggkJumpAnim"];
}

- (void)addJumpHighAnimation{
    [self addJumpHighAnimationCompletionBlock:nil];
}

- (void)addJumpHighAnimationCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock{
    if (completionBlock){
        CABasicAnimation * completionAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"completionAnim"];;
        completionAnim.duration = 3;
        completionAnim.delegate = self;
        [completionAnim setValue:@"JumpHigh" forKey:@"animId"];
        [completionAnim setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"needEndAnim"];
        [self.layer addAnimation:completionAnim forKey:@"JumpHigh"];
        [self.completionBlocks setObject:completionBlock forKey:[self.layer animationForKey:@"JumpHigh"]];
    }

    NSString * fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    ////ggk animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation * ggkPositionAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    ggkPositionAnim.values    = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(150, -300)]];
    ggkPositionAnim.keyTimes  = @[@0, @1];
    ggkPositionAnim.duration  = 1;
    ggkPositionAnim.beginTime = 2;

    CAAnimationGroup * ggkJumpHighAnim = [QCMethod groupAnimations:@[ggkPositionAnim] fillMode:fillMode];
    [self.layers[@"ggk"] addAnimation:ggkJumpHighAnim forKey:@"ggkJumpHighAnim"];
}

#pragma mark - Animation Cleanup

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    void (^completionBlock)(BOOL) = [self.completionBlocks objectForKey:anim];;
    if (completionBlock){
        [self.completionBlocks removeObjectForKey:anim];
        if ((flag && self.updateLayerValueForCompletedAnimation) || [[anim valueForKey:@"needEndAnim"] boolValue]){
            [self updateLayerValuesForAnimationId:[anim valueForKey:@"animId"]];
            [self removeAnimationsForAnimationId:[anim valueForKey:@"animId"]];
        }
        completionBlock(flag);
    }
}

- (void)updateLayerValuesForAnimationId:(NSString *)identifier{
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"Jump"]){
        [QCMethod updateValueFromPresentationLayerForAnimation:[self.layers[@"ggk"] animationForKey:@"ggkJumpAnim"] theLayer:self.layers[@"ggk"]];
    }
    else if([identifier isEqualToString:@"JumpHigh"]){
        [QCMethod updateValueFromPresentationLayerForAnimation:[self.layers[@"ggk"] animationForKey:@"ggkJumpHighAnim"] theLayer:self.layers[@"ggk"]];
    }
}

- (void)removeAnimationsForAnimationId:(NSString *)identifier{
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"Jump"]){
        [self.layers[@"ggk"] removeAnimationForKey:@"ggkJumpAnim"];
    }
    else if([identifier isEqualToString:@"JumpHigh"]){
        [self.layers[@"ggk"] removeAnimationForKey:@"ggkJumpHighAnim"];
    }
}

- (void)removeAllAnimations{
    [self.layers enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, CALayer *layer, BOOL *stop) {
        [layer removeAllAnimations];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: What was this tagged C#?

Comment: whats wrong with the code ? If it is a custom uiview, you can add it as a normal uiview to the root view controller on app delegate.

Comment: How to add it? Could you please give an example?

Comment: you can simply do this  [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubView:yourCustomView];

Comment: it says "unexpected interface name"